# Is it possible to localize an iOS app name based on region only?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, internationalization

I'm developing an internationalized version of my Cordova+Ionic app for iOS. The current app name is in Swedish, and I want to keep the name for the Swedish market, but the international app will have a new name.

I need the app to have the Swedish name for all users in Sweden, regardless of the chosen language. **Is it possible to localize the app name based on region only?**

I know you can localize it using a `InfoPlist.strings`  resource with `CFBundle(Display)Name` properties, but the locales used to determine what resource to use are (as far as I'm aware) solely based on the devices preferred language/locale setting and takes no consideration about the device's region setting.

For instance, the resource for the `en-GB` locale (located at `en-GB.lproj/InfoPlist.strings`) is loaded when the preferred language is set to *English (United Kingdom)*, but not for *English* with region set to *United Kingdom*.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, currently that is impossible

This is the extract from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AccessingaBundlesContents/AccessingaBundlesContents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH104-SW7):

> First, the bundle determines which localization to use for the application as a whole. If a .lproj folder exists for the preferred language, that localization is used. Otherwise, the bundle searches for an .lproj folder matching the next preferred language, and so on, until one is found. If there is no localization for a preferred language, the bundle chooses the development language localization.

Comment: @Christopher Bottoms I enriched my answer with the article from the official documentation